# Unix KSH counter - preserving leading 0s while incrementing

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I need to increment a counter in a loop. Requirement is like this:

```
$ echo $x
0000001
$ x=$((x+1))
$ echo $x
2
```

But, the counter should like this:

```
0000001
0000002
0000003
0000004
0000005
0000006
0000007
0000008
0000009
0000010
0000011
```

Comment: You just need to use `printf` to format the output

Answer (score 2):

You want `typeset -Z`.

From the docs:

> Right justify and fill with leading zeros if the first non-blank character is a digit and the -L option has not been set.  Remove leading zeros if the -L option is also set.  If n is non-zero, it defines the  width of the field, otherwise it is determined by the width of the value of first assignment.

```
$ typeset -Z 6 x
$ x=1
$ echo $x
>> 000001
$ (( x ++ ))
$ echo $x
>> 000002
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ echo $x
0000001
$ x=$((x+1))
$ printf "%06d" $(echo "$x" | bc)
0000002
```

With `printf` you can format the output. Now, it works also with **leading zeros**.

Comment: As a warning -- this works with ksh, but will break with some other modern shells, including bash, where 0-prefixed numbers are assumed to be in octal. On these systems, `$(( 07 + 1 ))` evaluates to `10`, and `$(( 08 + 1 ))` is a syntax error.

Comment: Why are you using the `f` format specifier instead of `d`?